# Extreme slow down of Manipulate in version 11.1.1 when adding Frame->True

Tags: plotting, front-end, dynamic, system-performance

Assigned CASE:3886109

---

I noticed something very strange in

```
 11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)
```

When I make simple `Manipulate` with only `Plot` in it and if I add `Frame->True` then the slider becomes *very slow* to respond.

Changing to `Frame->False` makes it fast and snappy again and I can move the slider very fast and it updates fast.

I tried the same code in version 11.0.1, and I do not see this problem at all. Both `Frame->True` and `False` keep the slider fast.

Here is the code below. To see the problem, simply move the slider using the mouse and you'll notice it is much slower to respond when `Frame->True`. I am on Windows 7.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[c x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  Frame -> False], (*change this to True to see the slow down*)
 {c, 1, 100, 1}
 ]
```

The question is: Why does it slow down when `Frame->True` in *Mathematica* 11.1.1? Any one else see this problem?

**Update**

Per Kuba comment below that it can be hardware related, here is information on the graphics card on my PC

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Windows 10, MMA 11.1.1 - slight slow down, not extreme. http://www.fastswf.com/Jwe4DIQ

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev thanks for checking. I am on windows 7, for me, it is a lot slower. Basically not usable at all. So I turned off the `Frame->True` for now.

Comment: On Mac 10.11 a slight slowdown

Comment: Windows 7 x64, *Mathematica* 11.1.1  - very significant slowdown, in version 11.0.1 - no slowdown.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thanks! I was worried it was just me seeing this. Very strange behavior of Manipulate with Frame.

Comment: @Kuba OK, will send email to wolfram support. I also changed the example to make it simpler. Initially I pasted the example I had at the time.

Comment: @Nasser additionaly it seems to be hardware dependent as I can test on two machines with Win10 V11.1.1 and one is terribly slow while the second one only slightly slower.

Comment: On MMA 11.1.1.0 on OS X 10.10.5 AMD Radeon HD 6000 slight but noticeable slow down as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please report this, even simple `Plot[x...` will do, and it seems the problem is with rendering as `RepeatedTiming` gives similar results for both.

Here is a reduced example with a workaround, which is not to trigger `Frame-ed` plot each time but only update plot's content:

```
Manipulate[
   Graphics[{
       Dynamic @ First @ Plot[
           x / t, {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 3}}
       ]}
     , PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 3}}
     , Frame -> True
     , AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
     , ImageSize -> 400
   ]
 , {t, 0.1, 100, 0.1}
]
```